# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "XXXXX@roadsprep.com" using 3 possible authenticators

Tags: laravel-5.4

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_NAME= 'NAME'
MAIL_USERNAME=XXXXX@roadsprep.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

This is in my .env file.

```
(1/1) Swift_TransportException Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "XXXXX@roadsprep.com" using 3 possible authenticators
in AuthHandler.php (line 181)
at Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler->afterEhlo(object(Swift_SmtpTransport))
in EsmtpTransport.php (line 332)
at Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doHeloCommand()
in AbstractSmtpTransport.php (line 118)
at Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
in Mailer.php (line 79)
at Swift_Mailer->send(object(Swift_Message), array())
in Mailer.php (line 443)
at Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(object(Swift_Message))
in Mailer.php (line 217)
```

This error showing me in my home desktop but this same setting perfectly running in my office machine. Both from localhost.

Comment: Allow less secure apps: ON : THIS OPTION ENABLED FROM THE START IN GMAIL.

Comment: looked other suggestions but didn't understand bit much. Help me. Thanks in advance.